# show only one column of data of 2D array of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am making a very simple custom directive, which will show, one column of product details, that is present in scope, as 2D array. The custom directive, will have an attribute, that will pass, which column of array has to be shown . Please see following plnkr--

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/zVIRZ8ADdQB4X8dSFOaJ
```

From UI I am using this--

```
<show-products type="name"></show-products>
```

Currently all data of the array is showing. but i need to show only 1 column of data and that column will be mentioned by directive attribute(for example -name as in plnkr)

In link function I am able to get the column name by using following code-

```
link: function postlink(scope, element, attr) {
      console.log("...type..." + attr["type"]); // prints name
    }
```

but how to pass that field name to template?

```
template: '<div ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}</div>' // i need to print only name column here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get those attributes for the template function as well, just create a function instead of a string and pass your attribute type into the product type variable.

The documentation for the function version of the template can be found in the angular v1 documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

For more see the snippet below.

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title>Directives</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module("app", []);

    angular.module("app")
      .controller("ctrl", ctrl)
      .directive("showProducts", showProducts);

    function ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.products = [{
        name: "Apples",
        category: "Fruit",
        price: 1.20,
        expiry: 10
      }, {
        name: "Bananas",
        category: "Fruit",
        price: 2.42,
        expiry: 7
      }, {
        name: "Pears",
        category: "Fruit",
        price: 2.02,
        expiry: 6
      }];
    };


    function showProducts() {
      return {
        template: (child, attributes) => {
          return `<div ng-repeat="x in products">{{x["${attributes["type"]}"]}}</div>`
        }
      };

    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="ctrl">
      <show-products type="name"></show-products>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant staff.

Comment: If this code helps, please consider upvoting it. @DebnathChakraborty